# C# Lock Object in multiple methods

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have the below code.

```
public class AgeIncrementor
{
    private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
    public AgeIncrementor()
    {
        Age = 0;
    }

    public int Age { get; set; }
    public void IncrementAge()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
         {
             try
             {
                 lock (syncLock)
                 {
                     Age += 10;
                     Console.WriteLine("Increased to {0}", Age);
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
             }
         });

    }
    public void Complete()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Printing from Complete() method.");
    }
}
```

and the main method code is as below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var ageIncrementor = new AgeIncrementor();
        Console.WriteLine("Age is {0}", ageIncrementor.Age);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            ageIncrementor.IncrementAge();
        }

        ageIncrementor.Complete();
        Console.WriteLine("Completed");
        Console.WriteLine("Final Age is {0}", ageIncrementor.Age);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

My expectation is that  All threads will be completed when I call Complete() method and I am expecting the output as below.

```
Age is 0
Increased to 10
Increased to 20
Increased to 30
Increased to 40
Increased to 50
Printing from Complete() method.
Completed
Final Age is 50
```

But I am getting the following output as shown below.

```
   Age is 0
   Printing from Complete() method.
   Completed
   Final Age is 0
   Increased to 10
   Increased to 20
   Increased to 30
   Increased to 40
   Increased to 50
```

How do I make sure all threads running the IncrementAge() method should have executed?

Comment: Lock just makes sure that multiple threads don't enter the protected code at the same time.  I think you have to look more at waiting for all the tasks to complete.  Maybe return the task and store it in an array then call [`Task.WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I think you need to 1) save the Task from `IncrementAge()` in a member variable and 2) wait on it to complete in `Complete()`

Alternatively you could return the `Task` from `IncrementAge()` and wait on all of them using [`Task.WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Locking has nothing to do with order of execution..  It just prevents multiple access.

Comment: The lock keyword can be used to ensure that a block of code runs to completion without interruption by other threads. This is accomplished by obtaining a mutual-exclusion lock for a given object for the duration of the code block. - MSDN

Answer (score 4):

You are starting multiple threads but not waiting for them to complete. `lock` is just a [Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx) and as no control over order.  If you change your `IncrementAge` to return the `Task` and then await the Tasks your code will complete correctly.  As a note it is possible for this to still run out of order.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ageIncrementor = new AgeIncrementor();
        Console.WriteLine("Age is {0}", ageIncrementor.Age);

        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
                              .Select(i => ageIncrementor.IncrementAge(i))
                              .ToArray();

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        ageIncrementor.Complete();
        Console.WriteLine("Completed");
        Console.WriteLine("Final Age is {0}", ageIncrementor.Age);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

// watch the numbers passed in when the different tasks were started

public class AgeIncrementor
{
    //doesn't need to be static since you are only using one instance
    private readonly object syncLock = new object();
    private Random Random = new Random();

    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Task IncrementAge(int index)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // act like work before lock
            Thread.Sleep(this.Random.Next(10) * 10);
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                // act like work before change                      
                Thread.Sleep(this.Random.Next(10) * 10);
                Age += 10;                    
                // act like work after change before release
                Thread.Sleep(this.Random.Next(10) * 10);
                Console.WriteLine("Increased to {0} ({1})", Age, index);
            }
        });
    }
    public void Complete()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Printing from Complete() method.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lock just makes sure that multiple threads don't enter the protected code at the same time.  I think you have to look more at waiting for all the tasks to complete.  Maybe return the task and store it in an array then call [`Task.WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx)

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/h3c1Tt):

```
var ageIncrementor = new AgeIncrementor();
Console.WriteLine("Age is {0}", ageIncrementor.Age);
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(ageIncrementor.IncrementAge());
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
ageIncrementor.Complete();
Console.WriteLine("Completed");
Console.WriteLine("Final Age is {0}", ageIncrementor.Age);
Console.ReadKey();
```